# How to connect with Tenvis IP camera from java application using OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, video, video-streaming, ip-camera

> I have Tenvis **IP camera** with a username and password. I want to capture live photo or video from it in a simple java application developed in Eclipse IDE using **OpenCV**.
>
> I am using following code to serve my purpose.

```
public class Hello {

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
       try
       {
            System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
            System.out.println("m = " + m.dump());

 // VideoCapture cap= new VideoCapture("D:/css/pizzavideo.mp4");

VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture("http://192.168.2.106:7777/video/livesp.asp? 
user=admin&pwd=admin&resolution=32"); 

           if(cap.isOpened())
           {
               System.out.println(" camera found----"+cap);   

                    Mat frame = new Mat();
                    while(true){
                        if (cap.read(frame)){
                            System.out.println("Frame Obtained");
                            System.out.println("Captured Frame Width " + frame.width() + " Height " + frame.height());
                            Highgui.imwrite("img1.jpg", frame);

                            System.out.println("OK");
                            break;
                        }
                    }      
           }
           else
           {   
               System.out.println("Did not connect to camera");   
           }
               cap.release();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Exception---"+e.getMessage());
       }
    }
```

}

> Result :`When using http://192.168.2.106:7777/video/livesp.asp? 
>       user=admin&pwd=admin&resolution=32`

```
   Welcome to OpenCV 2.4.8.0
   m = [1, 0, 0;
        0, 1, 0;
        0, 0, 1]
   Did not connect to camera
```

> Result (I am successfully getting a frame of video as img1.jpg): When using  D:/css/pizzavideo.mp4

```
   Welcome to OpenCV 2.4.8.0
   m = [1, 0, 0;
        0, 1, 0;
        0, 0, 1]
    camera found----org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture@87816d
    Frame Obtained
    Captured Frame Width 480 Height 262
    OK
```

> **Please reply if any one knows how to connect my IP Camera and take photos or video in my  java application?**

Comment: I have tried this **VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture("h ttp://username:password@ip:port/video/livesp.asp");**  also but unable to connect with IP camera. Please reply if any one can sort this problem